# Escaping regex unicode string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode

I have a user defined string.
I want to use it in regex with small improvement: search by three apostrophes instead of one.
For example,

```
APOSTROPHES = re.escape('\'\u2019\u02bc')
word = re.escape("п'ять")
word = ''.join([s if s not in APOSTROPHES else '[%s]' % APOSTROPHES for s in word])
```

It works good for latin, but for unicode list comprehension gives the following string:
`"[\\'\\\\u2019\\\\u02bc]\xd0[\\'\\\\u2019\\\\u02bc]\xbf[\\'\\\\u2019\\\\u02bc][\\'\\\\u2019\\\\u02bc][\\'\\\\u2019\\\\u02bc]\xd1[\\'\\\\u2019\\\\u02bc]\x8f[\\'\\\\u2019\\\\u02bc]\xd1[\\'\\\\u2019\\\\u02bc]\x82[\\'\\\\u2019\\\\u02bc]\xd1[\\'\\\\u2019\\\\u02bc]\x8c"`

Looks like it finds backslashes in both strings and then substitutes APOSTROPHES

Also, `print(list(w for w in APOSTROPHES))` gives `['\\', "'", '\\', '\\', 'u', '2', '0', '1', '9', '\\', '\\', 'u', '0', '2', 'b', 'c']`.

How can I avoid it? I want to get `"\п[\'\u2019\u02bc]\я\т\ь"`

Comment: Why not just replace `"'"` with `['\\u2019\\u02bc]` *after* applying `re.escape`?

Answer (score 3):

What I understand is: you want to create a regular expression which can match a given word with any apostrophe:

The RegEx which match any apostrophe can be defined in a group:

```
APOSTROPHES_REGEX = r'[\'\u2019\u02bc]'
```

For instance, you have this (Ukrainian?) word which contains a single quote:

```
word = "п'ять"
```

**EDIT:** If your word contains another kind of apostrophe, you can normalize it, like this:

```
word = re.sub(APOSTROPHES_REGEX , r"\'", word, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

To create a RegEx, you escape this string (because in some context, it can contains special characters like punctuation, I think). When escaped, the single quote "'" is replaced by an escaped single quote, like this: r"\'".

You can replace this r"\'" by your apostrophe RegEx:

```
import re
word_regex = re.escape(word)
word_regex = word_regex.replace(r'\'', APOSTROPHES_REGEX)
```

The new RegEx can then be used to match the same word with any apostrophe:

```
assert re.match(word_regex, "п'ять")  # '
assert re.match(word_regex, "п’ять")  # \u2019
assert re.match(word_regex, "пʼять")  # \u02bc
```

Note: don’t forget to use the `re.UNICODE` flag, it will help you for some RegEx characters classes like r"\w".

Comment: This works only when user enters п'ять, it doesn't work when user enters п’ять.

Comment: @AndrewFount: OK, so you can "normalize" the word before escaping.